# Disabling numlock in session startup does not work

Tags: xubuntu, 17.10, startup-applications, xmodmap, numlock

I am trying to disable my numlock key using the following command

```
numlockx off && xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = """
```

It works so I wanted to this command to be run automatically at the start of any session. So I put it in the Application Autostart list. It did not work. The numlock works normally as if the command was not even run and I have to manually do it. How do I automate this at login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a bash script and put in ~/.local/bin
If the directory doesn't exist create it.

Then create the file.

```
 nano ~/.local/bin/numlockoff.sh
```

And add

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/numlockx off && xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = """
```

Make it executable

```
chmod 755 ~/.local/bin/numlockoff.sh
```

Finally add it to Session and Startup/Application Autostart

```
/home/username/.local/bin/numlockoff.sh
```